# WM_GETTEXT not showing correct text

Tags: c++, winapi

i am having issues with making an injectable notepad text viewer. I think I may have accessed the hwndEdit HWND wrongly. Currently when i run the program it shows

> ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

as the text

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    AllocConsole();
    SetConsoleTitleA("Notepad Viewer");
    FILE *c;
    freopen_s(&c, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen_s(&c, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);

    DWORD hwndEditAddress = 0x41E1B4;
    HWND hwndEdit = *(HWND*)&hwndEditAddress;

    for (;;) {
        TCHAR text[256];
        SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]), LPARAM(text));
        std::cout << "Current Text: " << text;
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you use std::wcout?

Comment: @Asesh same thing

Comment: What does SendMessage return?

Comment: What is the code actually trying to do. What on earth is the code that purports to obtain a window handle doing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
it is accessing a handle to notepad's text box and is trying to read it.

Comment: Well, I very much doubt that. How did you conclude that 0x41E1B4 is the value of a window handle?

Comment: BTW: what is the purpose of `DWORD hwndEditAddress = 0x41E1B4; HWND hwndEdit = *(HWND*)&hwndEditAddress;`? You could simply write `HWND hwndEdit = (HWND)0x41E1B4;`. But this is wrong anyway, the odds that 0x41E1B4 is the window handle of the edit control of your notepad are very small to the least.

Comment: How did you arrive at the constant `0x41E1B4`? Did you obtain it via Spy++?

Comment: @zett42 i obtained it through ida.
https://gyazo.com/4a23added354d63d541f99b6d1279221

Comment: @JujharSingh you probably used IDA incorrectly.

Comment: What you see in IDA is the address of a window handle, not the handle value itself. Because of virtual memory, this is address is not visible from your process. You would have to use `ReadProcessMemory()` to read the memory location where the handle value is stored from the notepad process (if this is what you want). Much easier and more reliable would be to use `FindWindow()` or `EnumWindows()` to obtain the window handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`╠` corresponds to the (extended) ASCII code 204, which is `0xCC` in hex. A sequence of `0xCC` bytes is used by the Visual C++ CRT to mark *uninitialized* memory. So, your output is basically a dump of some uninitialized memory region.

In your code, you call `SendMessge` passing the `hwndEdit` handle; but the logic you used to initialize this handle is unclear and smells of bug:

> ```
> DWORD hwndEditAddress = 0x41E1B4;
> HWND hwndEdit = *(HWND*)&hwndEditAddress;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

This code is strange

```
DWORD hwndEditAddress = 0x41E1B4;
HWND hwndEdit = *(HWND*)&hwndEditAddress;
```

You may as well write

```
HWND hwndEdit = (HWND)0x41E1B4;
```

Which has the exact same effect.

What happens next is that this value is not the value of a window handle. Therefore the attempt to read the text fails, and `text` is never modified. Finally, you print an uninitialized character array, which is undefined behaviour.

You need to revisit your logic that obtains the window handle.